# Polymer 3 - Unity3D WebGl

Tags: unity-game-engine, polymer-3.x

Has anyone ever succeed integrating Unity WebGl and Polymer 3?

I'm trying to make the webgl code a polymer 3 element, but I am still not able to do it. I could not find any tutorial or information about it.

In html I have to do the following:

head

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Unity WebGL Player | Test</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
<script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>  
<script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>

<script>
  var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/WEBdev.json", {
  onProgress: UnityProgress,
  Module : {
  cacheControl: {"default": "immutable"},
    }
});
```

head

body

```
<div class="webgl-content">

  <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1066px; height: 600px"></div> 

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="webgl-logo"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen" onclick="gameInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
    <div class="title">SOMA3D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

body

Any tips?

Comment: Could you please add your WebGl command that you want to run into Polymer 3

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question. Thanks in advance.